# Lost password on encrypted USB with AES-256. Is there any way to recover data?

Tags: usb, passwords, dump

I forgot the password for the USB flash drive (JQSC-XC002), the password is made up of numbers. But the problem is that there are 10 attempts, there are already 3 left.

The USB flash drive itself is encrypted with AES 256-bit. What do you advise, what to do. I took the dump, but then there’s no idea what to do next.

Comment: You can’t do anything. The data is encrypted, with only 3 attempts left (or even 7), there is absolutely no way to access your data without the password.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of encryption is to protect contents.

If you have forgotten the password and have no other source for the encryption password, then the contents are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Any brute-force use of any password cracker will require
perhaps millions of attempts with millions of passwords.
You don't have enough tries left for that.

Try to remember backward to the moment that you assigned
the password.
Perhaps you decided to use your birthday or some other number.
If you have used numeric passwords before, try to
recall your habitual passwords.

You have only three tries left, so better think carefully.
Once the three tries were done and failed, you may consider
the data as lost.